# Что происходит при scope provided в зависмости мавен

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, camunda

У меня есть зависимость в проекте:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.camunda.bpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>camunda-engine</artifactId>
  <version>7.15.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

В томкате(в котором разворачиваю проект) в папке lib лежит camunda-engine-7.11.0

Это работает.
Мне так казалось это не должно работать.
Или если версии не сильно отличаются, это будет работать пока не наткнусь на эти различия?

Comment: provided - значит вы потом сами обеспечите её наличие при запуске. Например, вы пишете веб-приложение для сервера приложений, в котором есть какие-то библиотеки, вы их используете - они вам нужны для сборки, но в сборку war/ear вам их не нужно включать, тогда вы пишите provided

Comment: Не должно работать